# How to order alphanumeric value within a cell in MS SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to order alphanumeric value within a cell in MS SQL server.

Example -

There is a value in a column - CBA321, and my desired output is ABC123.

If anyone knows how can I sort it within a cell, it will help. Thank you!

Order By is not working here. I thing UserDefinedFunction or Scalar Function is one solution, but I am a beginner, so not knowing much about it.

Comment: `ORDER BY` orders rows, not characters within a string. What, in your logic, defines that `'1'` is "greater than" `'Z'` as well? What about something like `'%'`? What defines the order of the characters.

Comment: This looks like the job of your application layer, the database extracts the required data but your application should be where you implement such a process, or are you validating and storing input incorrectly?

Comment: The required solution related to application layer not DB layer (as mentioned in a comment). People don't do think like this in databases. But you can find useful tipps here for sorting algorithm: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972635/efficient-string-sorting-algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure SQL Database or SQL Server 2022 you can use `string_agg` over `generate_series` for this, eg

```
declare @v varchar(200) = 'CBA321'

select string_agg( substring(@v,s.value,1), '') within group (order by  substring(@v,s.value,1))
from  generate_series(1,len(@v)) s
```

which outputs

`123ABC`

because numerals come before alpha characters in my collation.  If you want the alphas first, something like

```
declare @v varchar(200) = 'CBA321'

select string_agg( substring(@v,s.value,1), '') within group (order by  case when substring(@v,s.value,1) < 'A' then 1 else 0 end, substring(@v,s.value,1) )
from  generate_series(1,len(@v)) s
```

Comment: I don't think there's *any* collations where numerals come *after* A-z, if I'm honest.

Comment: The answerer is David here, @ShubhamJha .

Comment: @David Thank you so much! It helps. Just wanted to check how can use a column (eg. Invoice) in a table (eg. Sales Report) to use this formula.

Comment: @David, can you pls help me to use this function for a column (Invoice) in Sales Table. I have 4million of records, so I hope it won't slow down